# mysql datetime field

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

I'm parsing a feed that contains a "created at" entry, formatted like this:

```
Thu, 08 Oct 2009 23:01:33 +0000
```

I need to be able to store this in a MySQL table, in a DateTime datatype. Then, I want to  select rows `WHERE` datetime clause equals or in range between dates and/or times.

I have two questions:

1. Will this string be acceptable as a MySQL DateTime datatype?
2. If yes, which query should I construct to get results from and between dates or hours?

Comment: if you are using php then i think u can use strtotime() to convert to timestamp and then convert to the mysql datatime format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something along these lines (in your language of choice) to turn your string into an acceptable mysql datetime:

```
$inputdate = "Thu, 08 Oct 2009 23:01:33 +0000";
$unixdate = strtotime($inputdate); //output: 1255042893
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixdate); //output: 2009-10-08 23:01:33
```

There are a few ways to find records between two dates, this is my favourite:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '2009-07-01 00:00:00' and date <= '2009-10-31 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Delilah,
Thanks for your answer
i followed your instruction and from some reason i get 
"2009-10-31 01:01:33" instead of
"2009-10-31 23:01:33"
any ideas why?

Comment: Hmm.. assuming your date() formatting and source of the date itself are all correct, the next thing I'd look at is timezone funnyness. If you haven't already, try defining the timezone at the beginning of the file, like so:
    date_default_timezone_set("GMT");

Answer (score 3):

You can find [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function usefull for date parsing in mysql.

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Thu, 08 Oct 2009 23:01:33 +0000', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%s +0000');
    -> '2009-10-08 23:01:33'
```

Available formats are the same as for [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will accept a string as a [date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) in the following format

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE datestamp = '2009-10-08 23:01:33';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where date1 between date2 and date3;
```